# Pull unique records from mysql where pageID 3 exists only

Tags: mysql

I have many ClientIDs to many pageids

Eg.

```
ClientID 1 PageID 3
ClientID 1 PageID 2
ClientID 2 PageID 3
ClientID 3 PageID 3
```

In a query I want to bring up the record with only PageID 3 exclusively.

So in my result i should get Client 2 and 3 and client 1 should be omitted out of the results... Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Should it get ClientID 1 as well?

Comment: No ClientID 1 should be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a client appears in more than one Page then there should be more than one row containing the clientId

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE PageID = 3 GROUP BY ClientID HAVING ( COUNT(ClientID) = 1 )
```

I have not tested this but should work.

**EDIT :**

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM tableName GROUP BY ClientID HAVING (COUNT(ClientID) = 1)) AND PageID = 3
```

This one is tested. The previous one does not give exclusive records.

Comment: Didn't work sorry - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I am not sure this is going to bring up exclusive records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE PageID = 3
```

Note by your example this gets ClientID of 1, 2, 3. However, you mentioned just wanting ClientID 2, 3.

Comment: I want to ignore client 1 as they also have pageID 2... I only want records with pageID 3 exclusively